# & operator optional in function pointer assignment

Tags: c, gcc, function-pointers

In the following code:

```
/* mylog.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for atoi(3) */

int mylog10(int n)
{
    int log = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        log++;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return log;
}

int mylog2(int n)
{
    int log = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        log++;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return log;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int (*logfunc)(int); /* function pointer */
    int n = 0, log;

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    logfunc = &mylog10; /* is unary '&' operator needed? */

    log = logfunc(n);
    printf("%d\n", log);
    return 0;
}
```

in the line

```
logfunc = &mylog10;
```

I've noticed that the unary `&` (address of) operator is optional, and the program compiles and runs the same way either with or without it (in Linux with GCC 4.2.4).  Why?  Is this a compiler-specific issue, or perhaps two different language standards being accepted by the compiler?  Thanks.

Comment: BTW- does this all mean that a function pointer "behaves in the same way" as a reference to function would behave?

Comment: @Kos: It might appear to behave the same way at the source-code level, although the similarity is purely superficial: the underlying abstract language mechanics is rather different. Yet, if you dig even deeper and look at the machine-level mechanics, you'll see that they appear to be the same again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Operator `&` is indeed optional when taking the address of a function in your context (assigning it to something). It is not compiler-specific, it follows from the formal definition of the language.

Symmetrically, operator `*` is optional when invoking the function through a pointer. In your example, you could invoke the function as either `(*logfunc)(n)` or `logfunc(n)`. You used the latter, but the former would work as well.

Answer (score 16):

You are correct that the `&` is optional.  Functions, like arrays, can be automatically converted into pointers.  It's neither compiler-specific nor the result of different language standards.  From the standard, **Section 6.3.2.1**, paragraph 4:

> A *function designator* is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the **`sizeof`** operator or the unary **`&`** operator, a function designator with type "function returning *type*" is converted to an expression that has type "pointer to function returning *type*".

Comment: I was downvoted as well, I have a strong suspicion these were rival downvotes... Here's a compensating up from me

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: One "rival's" stats don't show enough downvotes to make him the culprit. Which apparently puts me under the suspicion :) But I didn't do it! Must be some troll's downvotes.

Comment: @AndreyT: I am sorry for hastily assuming a rival downvote. I was obviously wrong. It must be the frustration speaking :)

Comment: @AndreyT, @Armen: I didn't get downvoted, but as you noticed, I have too few downvotes to be guilty. It's a set up ! I can prove my innocence !

Answer (score 8):

***Answering in C++. For C the same holds***

Quote from the C++ standard (4.3.1):

> An lvalue of function type T can be
>   converted to an rvalue of type
>   “pointer to T.” The result is a
>   pointer to the function.50)

The same for arrays. (4.2.1)

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array ofN
>   T” or “array of unknown bound of T”
>   can be converted to an rvalue of type
>   “pointer to T.” The result is a
>   pointer to the first element of the
>   array.

But please DO note that these are conversions and by no means is a function a function-pointer or is an array a pointer. HTH

Answer (score 5):

From the standard (6.3.2.1/4) :

> A *function designator* is an expression
>   that has function type. Except when it
>   is the operand of the sizeof
>   operator or the unary & operator, a
>   function designator with type
>   ‘‘function returning type’’ **is
>   converted to an expression that has
>   type ‘‘pointer to function returning
>   type’’**.

So yes, omitting the `&` yields a pointer to function anyway.