# Understanding Function Pointers in C

Tags: c, function-pointers

What will `(*PREDir->cfun) ( d, &tf );` responsible for in below piece of code:

```
typedef struct {
    FILE    *fp;
    char    queue[ NAMELEN ];
    char    fullpath[ NAMELEN ];
    char    fname[ NAMELEN ];
} TRW;

typedef struct {
    char    *dir_to_scan;
    void    (*cfun)();
} SCANNING;

static TRW  tf;
static SCANNING *PREDir;
char *d;

(*PREDir->cfun) ( d, &tf );
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like cfun is ever set to any actual function... do you have code that sets it anywhere?  Does the compiler give you any warnings about this code?  Or are you asking what is supposed to happen under what is likely undefined behavior?

Comment: This is simply a call to function which is registered with the function pointer `cfun`.

Comment: It isn't quite a duplicate (this question doesn't ask about `typedef`), but there is some useful (and some esoteric) information in [How `typedef` works for function pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357520/how-typedef-works-for-function-pointers/9357637#9357637).

Answer (score 2):

`PREDir` is a pointer to a struct. The struct contains a member called `cfun`, which is a pointer to a function taking an unspecified number of arguments and not returning anything.

The

```
(*PREDir->cfun) ( d, &tf );
```

calls that function with two arguments, `d` and a pointer to `tf`.

Comment: Isn't it a pointer to a function taking no argument? I alaways thought that... Does this mean one could point to either `void foo(int a)` or `void bar(char a, char b);` without any error nor warnings ?

Comment: @Eregrith: In C, a function taking no arguments would be `void foo(void)`. OTOH, empty parentheses mean "unspecified arguments". See also http://c-faq.com/decl/pfitypedef.html and links therein.

Comment: Thanks, I was tricked by the usual warning given by `-Wstrict-prototypes` which I always use. Is it possible to declare `void (*foo)();` without warning when using this flag?

Comment: @Eregrith: good for you using `-Wstrict-prototypes`; I do that too (and `-Wmissing-prototypes`).  No, you can't avoid warnings for function pointers declared like `void (*foo)();` if you compile with `-Wstrict-prototypes`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Does this mean this declaration is somewhat a bad practice? I can see why it is kind of dangerous, so I wonder what purpose it serves in the first place, or how could it be worked around....

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Doing some quick research it seems it serves ["compatibility with Old C"](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter4/function_types.html)

Comment: @Eregith: Yes; pre-standard C did not have prototypes so pointers to functions didn't have them either. There is still code around that was originally written back then and for which converting to prototypes is not trivial.  I've worked on a large code base (with origins as far back as 1982), and it was not trivial to replace the sloppy prototype-less pointers to functions with strict prototyped pointers.

Answer (score 0):

`cfun` is a pointer to a function that takes any arguments and returns void.

So `(*PREDir->cfun) ( d, &tf );` will call the function currently assigned to `PREDir->cfun` with the arguments `d` and  `&tf` (address of tf).

Make sure `PREDir` points to a `SCANNING` object that has its `cfun` field assigned or you will get undefined behaviour.

Comment: How is this normal, as cfun is defined as a pointer to a function which prototype should be `void foo(void);` ?

Comment: @Eregrith: this is C, and `void (*cfun)();` means 'pointer to function returning no value and taking indeterminate, but not variadic, arguments'.  In C++, it means 'pointer to function returning no value and taking no arguments'.  This is a big difference between C and C++.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Gee... Thanks ! I've been lied to all my first year in my school O_O hahaha...

Comment: @Eregrith: `void (*foo)(void);` means `foo` is a pointer to a function that returns no value and takes no arguments, in both C and C++, though the second `void` is both unnecessary and non-idiomatic in C++ (but necessary and hence idiomatic in C).  I previously noted 'but not variadic' — that means the function signature does not end with ellipsis.  You must have a full prototype in scope to call a variadic function, so calling `printf()` without a prototype in scope is undefined behaviour, for example.

Comment: @Eregrith Lied about what? How similiar C and C++ are? Yes, they like lying about that...

Comment: @glglgl No they never said they were similar, they are not that kind of school. That was a bit of a joke, I just figured it was this way because of the habits I took there :)