# What is the difference between defining a function type and a function pointer type?

Tags: c

As I know, I can define a function type:

```
typedef void (fn)(void);
```

and I can also define a function pointer type:

```
typedef void (*pfn)(void);
```

There are 2 functions. The first function's parameter type is a function, and the other is a function pointer:

```
void a(fn fn1)
{
    fn1();
}

void b(pfn fn1)
{
    fn1();
}
```

I implement a function callback:

```
void callback(void)
{
    printf("hello\n");
}
```

and pass it as the argument to a and b:

```
int main(void) {
    a(callback);
    b(callback);
    return 0;
}
```

Both a and b work well, and print `"hello"`.

So I want to know what is the difference between defining a function type and a function pointer type? or actually, they are same?

Comment: See also [Understanding `typedef`s for function pointers in C — examples, hints and tips, please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591361/understanding-typedefs-for-function-pointers-in-c-examples-hints-and-tips-ple) and [How `typedef` works for function pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357520/how-typedef-works-for-function-pointers/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the abuse you can use with function pointers (`&func`, `func`, `*func`, `**func`, … all end up as the same value for a function `func`), there are few practical differences between the two.  You can use `fn *` to indicate a pointer to function, which is not a trivial transform.

However, here's a mild adaptation of your code, using a non-parameter variable of type `pfn` and attempting (unsuccessfully) to use non-parameter variable of type `fn`.  This does not compile, so there is a difference when used at file scope (global) or local scope and not in a parameter list.

#### `pfn.c`

```
typedef void (fn)(void);
typedef void (*pfn)(void);

static void callback(void)
{
    printf("hello\n");
}

static void a(fn fn1)
{
    fn fn2 = callback;
    fn *fn3 = callback;
    fn1();
    fn2();
    (*fn2)();
    fn3();
    (*fn3)();
}

static void b(pfn fn1)
{
    pfn fn2 = callback;
    fn1();
    fn2();
}  

int main(void)
{
    a(callback);
    b(callback);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Compilation

```
$ gcc -g -O3 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     -Werror  pfn.c -o pfn
pfn.c: In function ‘a’:
pfn.c:13:5: error: function ‘fn2’ is initialized like a variable
     fn fn2 = callback;
     ^
pfn.c:13:8: error: nested function ‘fn2’ declared but never defined
     fn fn2 = callback;
        ^
$
```

Answer (score 4):

Function types are treated as the corresponding function pointer type in argument lists.

There are basically two practical applications of (non-pointer) function types:

1. Avoiding the function pointer syntax, if you find it too baroque.

   ```
   int apply(int (*f)(int), int x) {
     return f(x);
   }

   int apply(int f(int), int x) {
     return f(x);
   }
   ```
2. Declaring multiple functions of the same type.

   ```
   int add(int, int);
   int subtract(int, int);
   int multiply(int, int);
   int divide(int, int);

   typedef int arithmetic(int, int);
   arithmetic add, subtract, multiply, divide;
   ```

The latter can be extremely useful to avoid repetition. Note however that function types don’t let you use `const` to prevent the pointer from being reassigned. So this compiles just fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int pred(int const i) { return i - 1; }
int succ(int const i) { return i + 1; }

int apply(int f(int), int const x) {
  // Oops, didn’t really mean to reassign ‘f’ here.
  f = pred;
  return f(x);
}

int main() {
    printf("%i\n", apply(succ, 1));
    return 0;
}
```

You can avoid this potential source of bugs by making the pointer `const`:

```
int apply(int (* const f)(int), int const x) {
  // error: assignment of read-only parameter ‘f’
  f = pred;
  return f(x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
fn fn2 = callback;
```

is illegal in Standard C.

```
void a(fn fn1)
```

behaves exactly like `void a(fn *fn1)`. It is a special syntax permitted only in function formal parameter lists, similar to how `void b(int x[])` actually behaves exactly like `void b(int *x)`.  If you do `sizeof fn1` you will get the size of a function pointer.

BTW you have redundant parentheses in your definition of `fn`, this is simpler:

```
typedef void fn(void);
```

The pointer version requires parentheses to associate the `*`.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the last segment [Here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/78-function-pointers/)

which helps you understand typedef of the fucntion's and function pointer better.