# Function pointers C

Tags: c

I am trying to understand C function pointers. I made this example to describe what I do not understand about the `syntax` specifically.

```
//somewhere in a .h
void(*func_pointer)(int i);

//somewhere in a .c
void func_test(int i)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
}

//initializing the func_pointer
func_pointer = &func_test;// works as expected
func_pointer = func_test;//why this works ? left: pointer, right: function
func_pointer = *func_test;//why this works ? left: pointer, right: ?

//calling the func
(*func_pointer)(2);//works as expected
func_pointer(2);//why this works ? calling a pointer ?
```

Why is this syntax accepted ?

Comment: Is there a reason not to close this as a duplicate of [How do function pointers in C work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/)?  The reasons are mainly hysterical…I mean, historical.  Although you're mostly querying the newer, more recent, less encrusted notations.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I actually had this question opened in another tab as we speak. However in the answer, only `func_pointer = &func_test;` and `(*func_pointer)(2);` was used, which makes complete sense syntax-wise. I am just confused of why the other syntax cases even work at all, because I expected that it should give a compile error

Comment: You might also find [Understanding typedefs for function pointers in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591361/) helpful, too.  And I think you should look at [How typedef works for function pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357520/how-typedef-works-for-function-pointers/9357637#9357637).

Comment: In pre-standard C, the `(*pointer)(args)` notation was necessary for calling a function via a pointer, and the `&` was not used (because a function name is a sort of pointer to function).  Then the simpler `pointer(args)` notation was allowed by the standard, probably with some precedent.  The `&` didn't do any harm; the `*` I've never understood — look at the second question linked in my previous comment.  But the standard says "it shall be like this", so that is how it is.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks a lot, I will check all of this, looks interesting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`func_pointer = func_test` and `func_pointer = *func_test` work because function names are automatically turned into function addresses when used in this context. 
`func_pointer(2)` works because function pointers automatically dereference themselves, much like references. As to why they do these things, I don't know. Maybe it was decided the syntax was complicated enough already.